# When I calling method, query returning undefined

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

node-mysql `query` returning `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
Hash.prototype.GetHash = function()
    {
        var test;
        var connection = this.config.CreateConnection();
        connection.connect(function(err){
           if (err)
               throw err;
           else
           {
               var query = "SELECT hash FROM test WHERE id = 1";
               connection.query(query, function(err, rows, result){
                  if (err)
                      throw err;
                  else
                  {
                      test = rows[0].hash;
                      console.log(test);
                  }
               });
               connection.end(function(err){
                   if (err)
                       throw err;
               });
           }
        });
        return test;
    }
```

console.log will give me right result `1a2b3c4d`.
So. When I call this method to main method:

```
    var h = hash.GetHash();
    console.log(h);
```

Console give me result `undefined`.

So I tried to cast, retype, create a new object from string class:
 this object `test`
like:

```
var test = '';
var test = new String;
var test = new String(rows[0].hash);
```

And without succes :\
Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 4):

Node.js is asynchronous, your code `Hash.prototype.GetHash = function() {}` will not work as it returns the value immediately when called, but has not executed it as yet. So when you print test, it gives undefined.

To use your `test` that your function computes and you are trying to return, you must use callback with test as its argument to use it, after your function completes. You will have to do some changes in your function.

```
Hash.prototype.GetHash = function(callback){
//pass callback in arguments if you want it to be provided when calling
...  //compute test
//return test; Dont do return, do callback
callback(test);
}

//Your definition of callback should be
callback = function(h){
console.log(h);
}
```

See the tutorials to learn more:

1. http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/how-to-write-asynchronous-code
2. http://howtonode.org/control-flow
3. http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii